# Multiple Axes and Plots

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

sorry if the post, is not that good. It's the first one for me on Stack Overflow.
I have Datasets in the following structure:

```
     Revolution1   Position1   Temperature1   Revolution2   Position2   Temperature2
        1/min        mm            C            1/min         m            C
        datas....
```

I plot these against the time. Now I want for every different unit a new y axis. So i looked in the matplotlib example and wrote something like this. X ist the X-Values and d is the pandas dataframe:

```
fig,host=plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)
par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()

uni_units = np.unique(units[1:])
par2.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.2))

make_patch_spines_invisible(par2)
# Second, show the right spine.
par2.spines["right"].set_visible(True)
for i,v in enumerate(header[1:]):
    if d.loc[0,v] == uni_units[0]: 
        y=d.loc[an:en,v].values
        host.plot(x,y,label=v)
    if d.loc[0,v] == uni_units[1]:
      (v,ct_yax[1]))
        y=d.loc[an:en,v].values
        par1.plot(x,y,label=v)
    if d.loc[0,v] == uni_units[2]: 

        y=d.loc[an:en,v].values
        par2.plot(x,y,label=v)
```

[image: see the plot i get here...]

EDIT: Okay i really missed to ask the question (maybe i was nervous, because it was the first time posting here):

I actually wanted to ask why it does not work, since i only saw 2 plots. But by zooming in I saw it actually plots every curve...

sorry!

Comment: I think you forgot to actually ask a question here. What's the problem?

Comment: You are right, i edited it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want is to get subplots from the `Dataframe`.

You can achieve such using the `subplots` parameter within the `plot`function you have under the `Dataframe` object.

With below toy sample you can get a better idea on how to achieve this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"y1":[1,5,3,2],"y2":[10,12,11,15]})
df.plot(subplots=True)
plt.show()
```

Which produces below figure:
[image]

You may check [documentation about subplots for `pandas` `Dataframe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#subplots).

Comment: Nice! This is almost what i was looking for (except for setting subplots=false)!  Thanks! :-)

How do i add a third scale? Like as shown in my example?

Comment: Just get your data in a `pandas` `Dataframe` and generate the plot. The number of axes would be related to the number of columns the `Dataframe` has. If you find this answer useful please cosider to upvote and/or mark it as accepted.